# Problem in getting proper time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

i am not able to get proper time from a given time.
My code is as follows

```
NSArray * array_TimeSlotWith_StartDate = [ @"01/05/2010 10:15:33" componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSArray * array_TimeSlotWith_EndDate = [ @"01/05/2010 10:45:43"   componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@" array_TimeSlotWith_StartDate  ===   %@",array_TimeSlotWith_StartDate);
NSLog(@"array_TimeSlotWith_EndDate     ==       %@",array_TimeSlotWith_EndDate);

NSArray * Array_StartTime = [[array_TimeSlotWith_StartDate objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSLog(@"Array_StartTime     ==       %@",Array_StartTime);

NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:[array_TimeSlotWith_StartDate objectAtIndex:1]];
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:[array_TimeSlotWith_EndDate objectAtIndex:1]];
NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
NSLog(@"date 1%@",date1);
NSLog(@"date 2%@",date2);
```

It gives me value of date 1 as 1970-01-01 04:45:33 +0000 instead of this what i need is just the time an that should be  10:15:33.

And same for the end date also it gives log as 1970-01-01 05:15:43 +0000 instead of this it should output as only the time component with value 10:45:43 .

Answer (score 1):

Time doesn't exist without a date. If you don't specify any date, the date formatter will default to `"1970-01-01"`(Unix epoch). I hope [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301705/nsdate-is-converting-really-strangely/6302110#6302110) will help you.

Though the `date1` and `date2` don't contain the value you've expected, I feel that, `interval` should contain the correct result you need. I suggest you to just ignore the dates in this context.

Comment: SO what should i do to get the values which i expect means only the time components is needed.Plz help..

Comment: @abhi.shah88, you can not have the time alone in NSDate. NSDate should contain both date and time. Anyway, what you are going to do with the time in NSDate? I mean what is the purpose of it?

Comment: I am getting a date from websrvice(like this 01/05/2010 10:15:33) and what is want i the time component from that date not the whole date and time .Thats why if you can suggest any other approach it would be great. Hope you get what i want as output. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @abhi.shah88, You can not have time alone in NSDate, if you want time you can convert NSDate to NSString using the time format.

Answer (score 0):

you neither specifying the date and timezone that's the reason `NSDate` object pick the default one for its use.

Comment: So what should i do to get the output which i need.I just need is the time here.